# Problems with SafeCracker File field within Matrix

Tags: safecracker, matrix, error, file-uploads, safecracker-file

I am using EE 2.5.3 with Safecracker File fieldtype 2.1 and Matrix 2.5

I am having problems with a Safecracker form which has a matrix field containing a safecracker file upload field. I am using display inline for error messages.

1) If I upload an invalid file, no error message is triggered and the form submits. 
e.g. When I upload a non image file to an image only location, the form submits without error but the non image file is not uploaded.
e.g. When I upload an image larger than the max dimensions set, the form submits without error and the image is actually uploaded despite being larger than allowed.

2) If the form is submit with an error with another field in the form, the inline errors display and the other field values persist as expected but the safecracker file fields in the matrix just say Array and the files are lost.

If I just use a single Safecracker file field outside of Matrix, I do not have either of these problems, so it definitely seems to be Matrix related.
I am posting here because I understand this is now the primary support channel for Pixel and Tonic.

Comment: Hey tidy - can you update your post with some template code for your Safecracker form? Also, I'd recommend upgrading to EE 2.5.5 and Matrix 2.5.2 before more troubleshooting if possible.

Comment: Thanks for replies. Have tried Brian's ft.safecracker_file.php change but that just makes the matrix file fields blank on error instead of saying Array (which makes sense because the change converts an array to an empty string). Already had the patch referenced by Andris higher up that thread in place. Not in a position to upgrade EE to 2.5.5 on this particular site right now, and I realise that may well be necessary to get to the bottom of this.